# GFCI tripping based on incoming supply with no load

Tags: gfci

I am trying to understand how this is possible, but we have one location where multiple GFCIs trip immediately, even with no downstream connection.

The first assumption would be that those GFCIs are faulty, but when provide them with power in a different location, nothing happens: they don't trip.

The location where they trip is semi-rural, but we have good earth-to-neutral links on the incoming side 100M++ from where the GFCI is installed, and also in the distribution central where they are installed.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What sort of cable length do you have on the outlet side? What specific cable is it?

Comment: Is *100M++ from where the GFCI is installed* mean (a) power comes in -> distribution central -> GFCI -> 100M++ of wires? or (b) power comes in -> distribution central -> 100M++ of wires -> GFCI?

Comment: "we have good earth-to-neutral links ... in the distribution central where they are installed." Any earth-neutral connection on the load side of a GFCI will cause it to trip. Are these links in your distribution centre on the supply side of the GFCIs (and in accordance with your local wiring regulations)? If you disconnect the load side wiring from the GFCIs do they stop tripping? (That would suggest a fault in the load side wiring that causes the GCFIs to do their job and protect you.)

Comment: The earth-neutral link is on the supply side, not the load side.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it is: Incoming supply => main distribution central with earth-neutral link, => 100m underground cable => second distribution central with earth-neutral link => GFCI => breaker box => load. The GFCIs trip even if not connected to the breaker box.

Comment: @andy They trip even if no load is connected at all.

Comment: Are these GFCI/breakers or GFCI/receptacles or something else?

Comment: They are three phase breakers for installation in breaker boxes

Comment: Are these breakers only sensitive to ground faults/earth leakage or do they also protect against overload/short circuits?

Comment: Good question @GrahamNye, I will check the specifications next time I head out there. The thing that really confuse me is that they work fine when tested in the city, but they trip on the countryside. It makes me wonder if there is some "smart grid" thing or something else with the supply that can cause them to trip. It just doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Are the breakers pure GFCI only, or are they combination (with arc fault for instance)? Do they trip when powered elsewhere at the semi-rural site, for example where the 100M cable originates?

Answer (score 2):

### You have a ground fault.

That's what Ground Fault Circuit Interruptors are looking for.  Asking why one is tripping is like asking why a radon detector is going off.

Somewhere downline of the GFCI (or in something plugged into it, current is leaking along one of two paths:

- Hot to ground or earth
- Neutral to ground or earth

Test for resistance from hot to ground and from neutral to ground (downline of the GFCI with the GFCI tripped; the GFCI should interrupt neutral for you).

Note that some ground faults act like Voltage Break-over (VBO) devices; they insulate up to a certain voltage then conduct above that voltage.  Thus sometimes you can only get an effective test at line voltage.

> The location where they trip is semi-rural, but we have good earth-to-neutral links on the incoming side 100M++ from where the GFCI is installed, and also in the distribution central where they are installed.

Say what now?  You should only have earth-neutral bonds in places where your nation's electrical codebook tells you to put them.  Generally you only want ONE neutral-ground bond in an area where neutral and earth/ground are run as separate wires.  You want neutral current on the neutral wire only, and not dual-pathing on both neutral and ground (or neutral and dirt).

Comment: They trip even if there is no connection on the load side. No wires at all. It happened to multiple GFCIs.

Answer (score 0):

Either it's a wiring or other leakage problem on the load side of the GFCI (possibly in the box; there is a terminal for downstream loads), or the GFCI is defective, or the GFCI is responding to some kind of noise on the incoming power (which might or might not be a defect depending on just how ugly that incoming power is).

Check the wiring. Make sure nothing could possibly be leaking current inside the box. Try replacing the GFCI. If those don't resolve it you may need someone to bring in a power-line analyzer and/or to recheck your work.

Comment: My thoughts went to power quality as well. I'm really not sure whether awful harmonics etc on the lines could cause havoc -- seems plausible. Perhaps turning off or disconnecting as much other equipment at the site as possible would help test this. One hopes the power quality coming into the site is good!

Comment: I'm not sure either, but if it isn't the circuit, some form of induced signal is all I can think of, on the incoming power or as a completely unreasonable EMF.  Might not have thought of that if I hadn't encountered an old hotel that struggled to provide 90V and dropped below that periodically.